# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse to move to the next closing parenthesis?

Tags: eclipse

It seems like there would be a keyboard shortcut to move the cursor to the next closing parenthesis but I haven't found a question for it and I could really use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> works on '{','[','('.

Pressing the same short cut again takes you back to the original matching bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it helps, but double clicking next to an opening parenthesis highlights all the text untill the closing parenthesis and the scrollbar moves so that the closing prenthesis is visible.